# What is wrong in the below cte

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have

```
;with cte as
(
select rn=1, name = CAST('name'as varchar(50))
union all
select rn+1, CAST(name as varchar(50))+ CAST( (rn+1) as varchar(50))
from cte where rn<100)

select * from cte
```

error

**Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "name" of recursive query "cte".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
;with cte as
(
select  rn=1, 
        name = CAST('name'as varchar(100))
union all
select  rn+1, 
        CAST(name as varchar(50))+ CAST( (rn+1) as varchar(50))
from cte where rn<100)

select * from cte
```

You have to remember that all fields in the anchor and the recursive part have to be of the same type. That also goes for varchar fields.

Comment: so is it that the datatype length of the anchor and the recursive part should also match

Comment: Yes, when you converted the 2 parts in the recursive part, that would have allowed for 100 characters, whereas the anchor would only allow for 50